# Как делаются подписи на страницах в dompdf?

Tags: dompdf

Мне надо, чтобы на всех страницах снизу выводилась указанная мною подпись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура HTML документа для этого должна быть следующая:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Header and Footer example</title>
<style type="text/css">

@page {
 margin: 2cm;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
 margin: 0.5cm 0;
 text-align: justify;
}

#header,
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
 right: 0;
 color: #aaa;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}

#header {
  top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0.1pt solid #aaa;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0.1pt solid #aaa;
}

#header table,
#footer table {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: none;
}

#header td,
#footer td {
  padding: 0;
 width: 50%;
}

.page-number {
  text-align: center;
}

.page-number:before {
  content: "Page " counter(page);
}

hr {
  page-break-after: always;
  border: 0;
}

</style>
  
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Example document</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Author</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="page-number"></div>
</div>

<h2>Section 1</h2>

<p> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non
risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec,
ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula
massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci
nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit
amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat
in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero
pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo
in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue
blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed
pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales
hendrerit.</p>

<hr/>

<h2>Section 2</h2>

<p>  
 Ut velit mauris, egestas sed, gravida nec, ornare ut, mi. Aenean ut
orci vel massa suscipit pulvinar. Nulla sollicitudin. Fusce varius,
ligula non tempus aliquam, nunc turpis ullamcorper nibh, in tempus
sapien eros vitae ligula. Pellentesque rhoncus nunc et augue. Integer
id felis. Curabitur aliquet pellentesque diam. Integer quis metus vitae
elit lobortis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Morbi vel erat non mauris convallis vehicula. Nulla et
sapien. Integer tortor tellus, aliquam faucibus, convallis id, congue
eu, quam. Mauris ullamcorper felis vitae erat. Proin feugiat, augue non
elementum posuere, metus purus iaculis lectus, et tristique ligula
justo vitae magna. Morbi vel erat non mauris convallis vehicula. Nulla et
sapien. Integer tortor tellus, aliquam faucibus, convallis id, congue
eu, quam. Mauris ullamcorper felis vitae erat. Proin feugiat, augue non
elementum posuere, metus purus iaculis lectus, et tristique ligula
justo vitae magna.</p>

<hr/>

<h2>Section 3</h2>

<!-- yeah, we'll have to do better for inline floating elements -->
<p><span style="float: left; font-size: 4em; width: 0.7em; height: 0.9em; line-height: 1;">A</span>liquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

<p>Aliquam convallis sollicitudin purus. Praesent aliquam, enim at
fermentum mollis, ligula massa adipiscing nisl, ac euismod nibh nisl eu
lectus. Fusce vulputate sem at sapien. Vivamus leo. Aliquam euismod
libero eu enim. Nulla nec felis sed leo placerat imperdiet. Aenean
suscipit nulla in justo. Suspendisse cursus rutrum augue. Nulla
tincidunt tincidunt mi. Curabitur iaculis, lorem vel rhoncus faucibus,
felis magna fermentum augue, et ultricies lacus lorem varius purus.
Curabitur eu amet.</p>

</body></html>
```

Этот пример взят со страницы по этой ссылке: https://dompdf.net/examples.php#print_header_footer.html,html

Comment: Огромное спасибо, на неделю посмотрю. За ссылку вдвойне спасибо.